# How should I connect new drain?

Tags: plumbing, shower, drain, remodeling

I am updating my basement shower and need some help to connect a new drain. I have cast iron that runs under the foundation. Where it comes up in the shower I have no way to connect to it. Once the drain is installed I am planning on pouring a new shower pan with liner. The cast iron is 2". Here is what I have now.

[image: img]

[image: img]

Comment: If that were my project I'd be cutting out the concrete around that nasty pipe and attaching a length of PVC and a new trap. The concrete repair is trivial, and the benefit/failure prevention is significant.

Answer (score 1):

I typically use something like [this](http://www.homedepot.com/p/2-in-Service-Weight-Cast-Iron-Hub-to-2-in-Sch-40-PVC-Compression-Donut-P22U-205/100372278) for drains when I have to go into hard to access cast iron pipe. You stick it inside the cast iron pipe and then insert PVC into it. Make sure it fits very tight inside the cast iron pipe if you go this route.

Comment: Wouldn't that require the hub end of the cast iron to be there? This is a cut pipe.

Comment: I didn't realize my specific link was for a hub fitting. They make several different types of these fittings, including ones that will fit inside of a cut pipe.